# SourceTree can't clone Repository but still can create new remote one

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I have been using SourceTree for months in Windows but recently I turned to Mac. And I ran into a problem with it. I can create a new remote repository with SourceTree but I can't clone any Repositories from Bitbucket or Github. It said that `This is not a valid source path / URL`, I have tried so many ways and researches but It's not working.

PS: I have set Git version to System Git instead of Embedded Git but there is no change.

Do you have any idea to solve my issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The error message may be misleading you, because it doesn't actually tell you _why_ the URL/path is invalid.  Please check your credentials, as I suspect there could be a problem there.

Comment: thank you for your support, but can you tell me how to check it, i'm new with MacOS

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the answer, because of the newest version of SourceTree, I have to down to previous version.

Comment: Can you provide a link to any documentation of this being a known issue, such as a bug report or "known issues" list?

Answer (score 0):

First, in the remote account add you account, for example, the login with google.

Cloning a remote repository, in the field Source URL, try changing

```
ssh://git@bitbucket.org/[project]/[repository].git
```

for

```
https://[your-user]@bitbucket.org/[project]/[repository].git
```

Using Sierra, and sourceTree 2.4.1 (97)